# Oracle forms in web windows 7 jinitiator not working for IE9

Tags: java, oracle, internet-explorer-9, oracleforms, jinitiator

I was using oracle forms in WEB Windows XP with IE6 it was working well with J initiator. Now I switched to Windows 7 with IE9 I installed Jinitator but, IE is crashing.
Any solution ?

Answer (score 1):

There are several solutions for this.
Ditch jinitiator and switch to JRE 1.6.0_37.
Works on Windows XP and Windows 7 and Linux (REHL 5/6 AND FEDORA 17*).
Browsers tested IE7/8/9, chrome, firefox, safari.

What kind/version of application server are you using?
What kind/version of forms are you using?

*) YES You can install oracle 11.2.0.2 database, Weblogic 10.3.6 and Forms 11.1.2.0.0 on Fedora 17

Answer (score 1):

You should realize why in the past you should have used jinitiator and not a jre version. So here is some background:

When webforms gave birth oracle had a lot of bugs regarding to the java runtime. In that time java was from Sun and they didn't want to solve all the issues regarding oracle webforms. So instead of pushing Sun (if Oracle even could do that at that moment) they had the idea of doing the work themselves. So Jinitiator was the product to solve all these issues.

In the meantime Sun fixed all the problems (or at least most of them in the end of version 1.5 and the beginning of version 1.6 of java runtime), so jinitiator was becoming absolute.

At this moment java development is from Oracle and not anymore from Sun so all the problems will certainly be resolved and jinitiator can disappear from this world.

So the solution to you're problem is indeed install java runtime version in windows 7.

Hope this answer will give all of you a better insight in this matter.

Answer (score 0):

I only can offer you to try Netscape browser, on Windows 7 i am running Oracle Forms with Netscape and it works well.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the below and it worked.

Install Jinitiator as normal, if your having problems actually getting it to install, just use the Win7 ‘compatibility mode’ to get it to stay on your machine instead of it annoyingly uninstalling itself at the end of a failed install process.

Now

Replace the `jvm.dll` in jinitiator directory (`C:\Program Files (x86)\Oracle\JInitiator 1.3.1.13\bin\hotspot\`) with **this file** [jvm.dll](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/45390770/jvm.dll).

Restart `IE`* and try again, `Windows 7` should reduce your color scheme and your app should now work.